# Convert Objective-C enum to Swift String

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2

I'm trying to convert iOS error codes to String in Swift 2 (XCode 7.2). But converting to String returns the **type name** instead of the **value name** for system enums.

This is what I'm trying:

```
import CoreLocation
import EventKit

let clError = CLError.LocationUnknown
let clErrorString = "\(clError)"
// EXPECTED: 'LocationUnknown'. OBTAINED: 'CLError'

let ekError = EKErrorCode.CalendarIsImmutable
let ekErrorString = "\(ekError)"
// EXPECTED: 'CalendarIsImmutable'. OBTAINED: 'EKErrorCode'
```

But with enums declared in Swift, this works as expected:

```
enum _EKErrorCode : Int {
    case CalendarIsImmutable
}

let _ekError = _EKErrorCode.CalendarIsImmutable
let _ekErrorString = "\(_ekError)"
// EXPECTED: 'CalendarIsImmutable'. OBTAINED: 'CalendarIsImmutable'
```

I'm trying to avoid a Switch-Case with all posible enum values, or extending system types adding a custom description.

Comment: Does CLError have any properties that show the error message?

Comment: Only visible methods are `rawValue` and `hashValue`. Both return an integer value.

Comment: Obviously you'll need to extend the system types or use a switch case, why are you trying to avoid these?

Comment: Create a `switch` and assign each enum value a `String`. That's your only option.

Comment: @matt I'm trying to avoid enumerating through all values because it's not future-proof. Any new possible error added to a new iOS version would break the code.

Comment: No it wouldn't. That is why you have a default. Or use a dictionary. Just suck it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting String name of Objective-C @objc enum value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828769/getting-string-name-of-objective-c-objc-enum-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in the following way without manually checking the cases by using the `ClError.Code` extension

```
extension CLError.Code {
    func getErrorDescription() -> String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let clError = CLError.locationUnknown
print (clError.getErrorDescription())
```

Comment: uhm: tried in these days, on Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1, and it seems to me this approach does not work anymore. Had to resort to switch